# Where to set EnableRowsCache for Dev Express MVC GridView

Tags: devexpress-mvc

I've been following instructions to enable caching in Dev Express gridview for .Net MVC, but I can't seem to find the property EnableRowsCache.  Looking at my references, we are using v13.1.  If I search my object browser in Visual Studio, I do see the property on ASPxGridView.

My code looks like this:

```
var gridComboBox = Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.SettingsText.Title = "Account Info";
        settings.Name = "gvCustomerAccounts";
        settings.EnableRowsCache = true; //Doesn't compile, also flagged by Resharper
```

Was this property introduced on a later version, or is it not suitable for this gridview, or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Dev Express support, this property was added in version v2013 vol 2, after my edition.